# CMake MSVC: How to add a custom command for a single configuration? (Debug)

Tags: cmake

I would like to add the following command only for the Debug configuration:

```
if (MSVC)
    add_custom_command(TARGET my_target PRE_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${src} ${dst}) 
endif()
```

`src` and `dst` are just path strings.

I tried to adapt the code using examples I've seen in related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45455350/cmake-how-to-add-a-custom-command-that-is-only-executed-for-one-configuration), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996440/how-do-you-make-add-custom-command-configuration-specific-on-windows) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45455350/cmake-how-to-add-a-custom-command-that-is-only-executed-for-one-configuration).
But non of them worked. Either the specific case is slightly different or they simply execute the same command using a different argument for other configurations.
All of my adaptations attempts caused the command to be malformed or simply did not do the trick.

I would like other configurations to not have to add a command at all.

How can this simple task be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to nullify command using `true`

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${target_name} PRE_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E $<IF:$<CONFIG:Debug>,copy,true> ${src} ${dst}
  COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS)
```

if **not** in `Debug` you should have `cmake -E true ...` i.e. the `true` will turn the command as no op.

> `true` Do nothing, with an exit code of `0`.

src: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-command-line-tool

note: available since 3.16
src: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/3.16.html#command-line

Comment: Thanks, but I must say it looks rather cryptic. 'true' as first parameter to mean 'do nothing' is not intuitive.

Comment: personally it recall me bash syntax `true || ...` or `false && ...` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working using a dummy empty string for configuration other than Debug:

```
string(
APPEND copy_cmd
"$<IF:$<CONFIG:Debug>,"
"${CMAKE_COMMAND};-E;copy;${pdb_src};${pdb_dst},"
""
">"
)
add_custom_command(TARGET ${target_name} PRE_BUILD COMMAND "${copy_cmd}" COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS)
```

Note that the "" string is basically the 'else' of the if. it nullifies the command.